# how to delete everything after a blank space in access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2003

I have a table->column first-name with values:

```
Juan
Manuel l.
Richard Wit
```

I'm trying to do a query that return

```
Juan
Manul
Richard
```

I want to eliminate after a space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want SQL, try

```
SELECT MID(name  + " a", 1, INSTR(name + " a", " ")-1) AS FirstName FROM myTable
```

In VBA it would be similar, since Mid() and InStr() work exactly the same as in Access-SQL

---

Really, though, it would be better to just store first and last name in separate fields so you don't have to do this sort of finagling in the SQL.

Comment: I add the + " a" to prevent errors if the name dosn't have a space.

Comment: Don't you want to us `& " a"` since otherwise, if Name is Null, you'll end up with a Null? That is, in Access/Jet/ACE, the + concatenation operator propagates Nulls (i.e., `Null + " a" = Null` while `Null & " a" = " a"`).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Left([First-Name], InStr([First-Name] & ' ', ' ') - 1) As CleanFirstName
FROM table
```

Keep in mind that running this will be inefficient since you will be executing VBA functions against every record in your query.  Depending on how you are using this, you may want to have the query return the full field and do the processing after the fact.

Comment: Exactly. This is a presentation-layer issue and likely doesn't belong in the SQL.